# simplify the bulk of code

Tags: php

is there a way to make this code shorter the value of $val1 $val2 ....... is a result of a query

```
$val1 = 1;
$val2 = 2;
$val3 = 3;
$val4 = 4;
$val5 = 5;
$val6 = 8;
$val7 = 7;
$val8 = 8;
$val9 = 8;
$val10 = 9;
$val11 = 13;
$val12 = 12;

echo $val1.",".$val2.",".$val3.",".$val4.",".$val5.",".$val6.",".$val7.",".$val8.",".$val9.",".$val10.",".$val11.",".$val12; 

?>
```

is there i way to simplify this

```
echo $val1.",".$val2.",".$val3.",".$val4.",".$val5.",".$val6.",".$val7.",".$val8.",".$val9.",".$val10.",".$val11.",".$val12;
```

Comment: $val = range(1,12);
echo implode(',',$val);

Comment: are the mix ups like `$val6=8` intentional?

Comment: ahh ok..hey is this possible to a for loop "echo $val1.",".$val2.",".$val3.",".$val4.",".$val5.",".$val6.",".$val7.",".$val8.",".$val9.",".$val10.",".$val11.",".$val12;"

Comment: @ Flame what do u mean intensional?

Comment: He means: _Why is `$val6` not equal to 6?_

Comment: What does the query look like that is spitting out these variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php):

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 7, 8, 8, 9, 13, 12);
echo implode(',', $values);
```

Comment: is this the equivalent of this echo $val1.",".$val2.",".$val3.",".$val4.",".$val5.",".$val6.",".$val7.",".$val8.",".$val9.",".$val10.",".$val11.",".$val12;

Comment: Not the equivalent. It's just a convenient way to display arrays! By the way, **you should use arrays**.

Answer (score 1):

That is what arrays are for:

```
$vals = range(1, 12);
echo implode(',', $vals);
```

If you did not create an array first-hand you should convert the numbered variables into an array first:

```
$vals = array($var1, $var2, $var3, ... , $var12);
echo implode(',', $vals);
```

This would not change that much for the single echo call, but normally you can move it more up in the code so to reduce the complexity.

Answer (score 0):

Put it in an array and loop through it might work.

```
$values = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
   echo $value;
}
```